# how to mix Robolectric tests with Android testing framework?

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric

I'm pretty new to Android testing and its really giving me hard time,
I find some things easier to test with Android's instrumentation testing framework and some thing much more easier to test with Robolectric's shadow objects.

is there a way to have a test project which is a mixture of Robolectric and Android tests or the only way is to have two separate test projects ?

Comment: Personally I prefer put robolectric test in main application project.

Comment: if you put it in the same project, what are you doing about dependencies (Robolectric, android.jar, Mockito, etc..) ?

Comment: I use Maven as one stop solution, however it shouldn'tbe too hard to manage dependency jars via eclipse, for example after adt r17 release, use libs directory.

Comment: Gal Ben-Haim: did you get any better solution for this? Are you able to support continuous integration as well?

Comment: I'm now using IntelliJ IDEA and Maven, the parent project contains 2 sub project (app and integration-tests), the app project contains the app code under src/main and unit tests (Robolectric / Mockito / etc..) under src/test. this is a standard Maven project structure and both unit tests and integration tests can be run with Maven from the command line for continuous integration.